# How to generate kotlin using swagger

Tags: maven, kotlin, swagger, swagger-codegen

Trying to generate kotlin language code using swagger json

I'm using plugin in my pom.xml

```
                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <inputSpec>${my-location}</inputSpec>
                                    <language>kotlin</language>
                                    <configOptions>
                                    <dateLibrary>java7</dateLibrary>
                                    </configOptions>                                                                
                                    <library>jersey2</library>
                                    <modelPackage>abc</modelPackage>
                                    <apiPackage>test</apiPackage>

                                </configuration>

                            </execution>
```

throws me the error:

```
Execution default of goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.1.5:generate failed: Can't load config class with name kotlin Available: android
[ERROR] async-scala
[ERROR] csharp
[ERROR] dart
[ERROR] flash
[ERROR] python-flask
[ERROR] java
etc...
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Running maven command clean install. How do I generate the code for kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of the plugin - 2.4.12.

`kotlin` (client) was added in v. 2.2.3 and `kotlin-server` was added in v. 2.4.0.

Comment: cool, updated the library, but fails with Execution default of goal io.swagger:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:2.4.12:generate failed: Unknown library: jersey2. Do u know what library I can use?